# вопрос по классам от чайника java

Tags: java, классы

Как передать значение `eatTime1` класса `Setter`, в класс `Master` для метода `getFood()`?

Классы изучать начал недавно, объясните либо укажите тему которую мне стоит изучить.

```
public void getFood(int time, int food, int drink, String korm) {
    if(time == EatTime1) {
        System.out.println(korm);
    } else {
        System.out.println("потерпи");
    }
}
```

Все классы:

```
class Master {
    private String name;

    Master(String Name) {
        this.name = Name;
    }

    String GetName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void getFood(int time, int food, int drink, String korm) {
        if(time == EatTime1) {
            System.out.println(korm);
        } else {
            System.out.println("потерпи");
        }
    }
}


class Pet {
    Master person;
    int weigth, age, eatTime1;

    int eat(int food, int drink, int time, String korm) {
        if(time == eatTime1) {
            person.getFood(time, food, drink, korm);
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    void voice() {
    }
}


class Cat extends Pet {
    int mouseCatched;

    Cat(int Weight, int Age, int EatTime1) {
        this.weigth = Weight;
        this.age = Age;
        this.eatTime1 = EatTime1;
    }

    public void SetMouse(int kol_vo) {
        this.mouseCatched = kol_vo;
    }

    public int GetMouse() {
        return this.mouseCatched;
    }

    void toMouse() {
        System.out.println("Словил мышь!");
    }
}


class Dog extends Pet {
    void preserve() {
        System.out.println("не подходи!");
    }    
}


class Pointer extends Dog {
    public int EatTime1;
    String okras;

    Pointer(int Weight, int Age, int EatTime1, String Okras) {
        this.weigth = Weight;
        this.age = Age;
        this.eatTime1 = EatTime1;
        this.okras = Okras;
    }

    void rod() {
        System.out.println("Хорошая порода!");
    }

}


class Setter extends Dog {
    public int EatTime1;
    String slugba;

    Setter(int Weight, int Age, int EatTime1, String Slugba) {
        this.weigth = Weight;
        this.age = Age;
        this.slugba = Slugba;
        this.eatTime1 = EatTime1;
    }

    void dolg() {
        System.out.println(slugba);
    }
}


public class Lab8 {
    public static Setter tuzik = new Setter(10, 4, 5, "");
    public static Pointer sharik = new Pointer(15, 5, 4, "Золотой");
    public static Cat murka = new Cat(6, 2, 8);
    public static Master Hozjain_dobr = new Master("Вова");
    public static Master Hozjain_zloy = new Master("Петр");

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // TODO code application logic here
        murka.SetMouse(5);
        tuzik.person = Hozjain_dobr;
        tuzik.person.getFood(10, 2, 5, "Whiskas");
        sharik.person = Hozjain_zloy;
        tuzik.person.getFood(10, 2, 1, "Мясо");
        murka.toMouse();
        System.out.println("Словила мышей = " + murka.GetMouse());
        sharik.preserve();
        tuzik.preserve();
        tuzik.dolg();
        System.out.println(Hozjain_dobr.GetName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно в аргументе метода getFood(). В куске кода:

```
 if(time == EatTime1) {
```

EatTime1 и есть из класса Setter?

Если да, то можно так Setter.EatTime1, т.к. public, но при этом объект Setter должен быть в методе getFood() класса Master, передан в него в качестве аргумента или добавить свойство Setter в класс Master.

```
class Master {
    private String name;
    //новое свойство объект Setter
    private Setter setter;
    Master(String Name) {
        this.name = Name;
    }

    String GetName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void getFood(int time, int food, int drink, String korm) {
        if(time == this.setter.getEatTime1()) {
            System.out.println(korm);
        } else {
            System.out.println("потерпи");
        }
    }
}
    class Setter extends Dog {
        //инкапсулируем свойство
        private int EatTime1;
        String slugba;
        //геттер метод, необходимо добавить еще сеттер метод
        publict int getEatTime1() {
           return this.EatTime1;
        }
        Setter(int Weight, int Age, int EatTime1, String Slugba) {
            this.weigth = Weight;
            this.age = Age;
            this.slugba = Slugba;
            this.eatTime1 = EatTime1;
        }

        void dolg() {
            System.out.println(slugba);
        }
    }
```

Почитай книгу про ООП.